# Get cursor position in ScrollPane component

Tags: javafx, position, cursor, scrollpane, vbox

I have a JavaFX app where a Vbox contains multiple textarea children.
The VBox is then added to a ScrollPane.
Now if the user adds multiple lines the scrollPane does not automatically scroll to the cursors position, so the cursor is not visible anymore.

I already can listen to the heightproperty change and can set the scrollbar position by setting scrollBody.setVvalue.

My question is how can I get the current cursor position height relative to the scrollPane?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a TextArea which starts in the viewport, but has it's bottom edge - and some amount of the text area - below the bottom of the viewport?  And that when someone types into that area below the viewport it doesn't automatically scroll down?